# How to set proper element css direction (ltr / rtl) according to it's inner text (english / arabic)?

Tags: html, asp.net

I want to make right to left alignment of text for Arabic language & reverse for English on Button click. I can do this by changing every text alignment dynamically for English & Arabic that's lengthy process.

**So can any body gives an idea for doing in short. Any suggestion really appreciate.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can set content direction easily with css.

html:

```
<div class="rtl">اليمين إلى اليسار</div>
<div class="ltr">Left to right</div>
```

css:

```
.rtl{direction:rtl;text-align:right;}
.ltr{direction:ltr;text-align:left;}
```

**EDIT:**

to make this **dynamically happen on button click**, do as following:

javascript & **jQuery** (i suggest using jQuery in that case):

```
// function that returns true if input is arabic, else false
function is_arabic(str) {
    var arabic = /[\u0600-\u06FF]/;
    return arabic.test(str);
}

// on button click
$(function(){
    $('#buttonID').click(function(){ // assuming 'buttonID' is the button id
        $('div').each(function(){ // iterate all DIV elements 
            if (is_arabic($(this).text())
                $(this).addClass('rtl').removeClass('ltr');
            else
                $(this).removeClass('rtl').addClass('ltr');
        });
    });
});
```

just make sure to use the CSS rules a mentioned above.

hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I know this but hard-coding for each label is lengthy process. Suppose I have 100 of label in a page.

Comment: you just add the class `rtl` or `ltr` to each label, why is that a problem ?

Comment: I have to do this on Button click.. I just update my question.

Answer (score 3):

Add a **dir** attribute on your body or div as shown below

```
<div dir="rtl"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this solution

Add this class in CSS

```
.rtl{direction:rtl;text-align:right;}
```

then use this code in any items you want to be right to left

```
<div class="@(Model.RtlEnabled ? "rtl" : "")"> Your right to left text <div>
```

I use this in ASP.Net core you can change it for your code.